# `default` constructor with uninitialized member in constant expression

Tags: c++, constexpr

The following minimal example is rejected by both Clang and GCC for not initializing the array data-member:

```cpp
class vector3
{
public:
    constexpr vector3() = default;
private:
    float m_data[3];
};

constexpr auto vec = vector3{};
```

Which yields the reasonably straight-forward error:

```
<source>:4:15: error: explicitly defaulted function 'constexpr vector3::vector3()' cannot be declared 'constexpr' because the implicit declaration is not 'constexpr':
    4 |     constexpr vector3() = default;
      |               ^~~~~~~
<source>:6:11: note: defaulted default constructor does not initialize 'float vector3::m_data [3]'
    6 |     float m_data[3];
      |           ^~~~~~
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Kvh8Wf3P3)</kbd>

The goal with the above code was to ensure that `vector3` can be used in constant expressions via value-initialization (e.g. `vector3{}`), which will zero-initialize the sub-elements (`m_data`).

The error occurs due to the use of the `constexpr` keyword, and the fix is simply to remove the keyword and to allow `default` to correctly deduce whether this can be used in a constant expression:

```cpp
class vector3
{
public:
    vector3() = default;
private:
    float m_data[3];
};

constexpr auto vec = vector3{}; // now works?
```

Curiously, this actually *now works* -- and is still able to produce a constant expression, with `m_data` being zero-initialized, as visible in the assembly for GCC (Similar exists in Clang, but with XOR instructions):

```
vec:
        .zero   12
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PYod6Y6z1)</kbd>

**My question is:** How is it possible that `= default` produces a (valid) `constexpr` constructor, whereas `constexpr ... = default` fails due to it not being valid for `constexpr`?

---

This question appears to affect C++ versions prior to C++20 (C++11 through C++17). Was this changed in C++20?

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/38rGedeeE)</kbd>

Comment: `The goal with the above code was to ensure that vector3 can be used in constant expressions via aggregate initialization` A simple solution: `struct vector3 { float m_data[3]; };` That can be used in constant expressions and can be aggregate-initialised. Or alternatively: `using vector3 = std::array<float, 3>;`

Comment: @eerorika Thank you, but the question already explains that the `constexpr` keyword is the cause of the issue here, and that dropping this still allows for proper value-initialization of the members within constant expressions; I was only inquiring *why* the `constexpr` keyword was the issue. It's also worth mentioning that the above is a minimal example, and the suggestions are not viable alternatives for a more constructed OO class that is not meant to model just an array. (**Edit:** I just realized I used the term "aggregate initialization" when I meant "value". Sorry for any confusion!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's true that in C++20, the rules were changed so that a `constexpr` constructor is no longer required to initialize all non-static members and base class subobjects.

Prior to C++20, we have the interesting situation that your constructor cannot be declared `constexpr`, but objects of the `vector3` type can still be used in constant expressions, because a default constructor that is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration is not actually *called* during value-initialization unless it is nontrivial (C++17 [dcl.init]/8.2) and thus the prohibition on calling non-`constexpr` functions within a constant expression is not triggered. This is not a compiler bug; it's just a quirk in the language.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt, succinct, and informative answer. Just to clarify your point on C++20's `constexpr` no longer requiring initialization: do these objects still get value-initialized to `0`? Or does this mean that `constexpr vector3() = default` has different behavior than `vector3() = default` in previous C++ versions without the `constexpr` (since you said the constructor doesn't get called during value initialization)?

Comment: @Human-Compiler A defaulted default constructor does not initialize scalar members. They are uninitialized and reading from them is UB (which means it would be ill-formed to do it inside a constant expression). However, if the object has static storage duration then it has already been initialized during the static initialization phase so it is not UB.

Comment: Ah, I see; so it only really affects its use when uninitialized inside a constant expression, which would not have been possible prior to C++20. I just wanted to make sure you weren't meaning that a constant constructed from this constructor would be UB to read from later on at runtime in C++20 (which would be bad). Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Right, I was referring to the value-initialization that should occur from using braced construction with the `default` constructor (e.g. `constexpr auto vec = vector3{};`). As you said, prior to C++20 this bypasses the constructor call for the initialization. I wasn't sure if you were meaning that, as of C++20, this no longer bypasses the constructor (though I believe you've clarified that this does not change). I know that trivial constructors will do no actual work (which was not what I was referring to here)

Comment: @Human-Compiler Sorry, you're right. When you value-initialize `vector3`, which has a non-user-provided default constructor, the object is zero-initialized and the constructor is not called. This is true in all versions of C++. This avoids any possibility of UB.